# Why does the word ''inseparable'' put between the words ''as an'' and ''whole''?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase "as an inseparable whole" mean?
Is putting the word "inseparable" between the phrase "as an whole" only for emphasis?

The context:

> If it were really the case that the new individual, as an inseparable
> whole, was begotten by its parents, twins could never exhibit totally
> opposite tendencies. In such a case, children, especially twins,
> would, with positively no exception, always be found to possess the
> same character as the parents.

Source:
[Collected Wheel Publications Volume XXVI: Numbers 394–411](https://books.google.com.mm/books?id=Dgc4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=from+without.+If%0Ait+were+really+the+case+that+the+new+individual,+as+an+inseparable+whole,+was%0Abegotten+by+its+parents,+twins+could+never+exhibit+totally+opposite+tendencies.&source=bl&ots=JopFexVtcI&sig=ACfU3U0O-hYqCMQ-ZyDQGaZqLYdcTY2OSA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivt-uKv7n8AhXbR2wGHVHJBUQQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=from%20without.%20If%20it%20were%20really%20the%20case%20that%20the%20new%20individual%2C%20as%20an%20inseparable%20whole%2C%20was%20begotten%20by%20its%20parents%2C%20twins%20could%20never%20exhibit%20totally%20opposite%20tendencies.&f=false)

Comment: Adding emphasis isn't the *only* justification for including ***inseparable*** in your cited context. It also ensures the reader doesn't get misled / sidetracked by irrelevant and unwanted allusions to ***on the whole***. What with "test-tube babies" and other medical advances, it's already possible today to say that a child was produced "on the whole" by the parents (with help from the fertility clinic! :), but that's certainly not something your cited writer wants to get involved in. He's only concerned with "nature / nurture" as competing "origins".

Comment: What do you believe "inseparable" means in this context? We can look at something as a whole even though it can be separated into parts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if my parents said that the Smith neighbours' child was produced 'on the whole' or 'more or less' by Mrs and Mrs Smith, one might suspect the milkman of some involvement in the matter.